# Docker share file-permissions with ubuntu user

Tags: docker, ubuntu, permissions

frequently I've been running into issues with docker. Whenever I execute composer from within the container, I am not able to edit the installed files before chowning the files from outside the container again. Is it possible to pass my user (I've seen this before, but does it fix the problem?) to my docker-compose, so that docker installs all the files pretending to be me? What is the best practice here, or how do you do it in your projects?

For example:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose exec php bash (enter container)
$ composer install bla (everything works fine)
$ ctrl + d (exit the container)
$ composer require bla/bla (yields the below error message)
```

> ./composer.json is not writable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best practices I'm used to involve running tools like `composer` that are actual build steps during your `Dockerfile`, and not trying to use Docker to install code or libraries on your host.  `docker exec` shouldn't be part of your core workflow; reserve it for a debugging tool.

Comment: @DavidMaze makes sense. If I run my composer install via my dockerfile, will the issue persist though? Or should I add the proper user in the dockerfile then? If I run the container as me (`CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose up` and in docker-compose `user: ${CURRENT_UID})`, it won't boot properly because port 80 is reserved for root (`php_1      | (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
`)

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is to run a docker container as a non-root user, you could do something like this:

```
docker container run --user 1000:1000
```

If you need to run the container with the current user, change it to `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`

In this [post](https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15) it's pretty well explained.